# Replace text starting with @ with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page, Now I am displaying a string which contains text starting with '@'. What I need to do is to replace all texts in a string starting with '@' with anchor tag using javascript something like

E.g:

**My string:**

had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach.

**Required output:**

```
had a great time with <a href="http://example.com/sarah333">@sarah333</a> and <a href="http://example.com/kevin9099">@kevin9099</a>  at beach.
```

Comment: And What have you tried to get this output?

Comment: var wordsBegginingWithAt = text.split(' ').filter(function(word){return word[0] === '@';}).forEach(function(word){text.replace(word, '<a href="'+word+'">'+word+'</a>')});

text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
str = 'had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach.';
replacedStr = str.replace(/\s\@(.*?)(\s|$)/g, ' <a href="http://example.com/$1">@$1</a>$2');
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way

```js
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = 'Result: ' +
  'had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach.'.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '<a href="http://example.com/$1">@$1</a>');
```

```html
<div id='s'>Source: had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach.</div>
<div id='r'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Php

```
$str = "had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach";
$str = preg_replace('/\B\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})/', '<a href="http://example.com/$1" class="primary-black">$0</a>', html_entity_decode($str));
echo $str;
```

In Javascript

```
var str = "had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach";
str = str.replace(/@(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim, '<a class="primary-black" href="http://www.google.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

Comment: in tags - javascript, not a php

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function CreateInput(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    var tbl=document.getElementById("tbl");
    var str = "had a great time with @sarah333 and @kevin0955 at beach.";

    replacedStr = str.replace(/\s\@(.*?)(\s|$)/g, ' <a href="http://example.com/$1">$1</a>$2');

    if(key == 13)
   {
     tbl.innerHTML += replacedStr;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onKeypress="CreateInput(event)">
<table id="tbl"> 
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and you get `Required output:` from question?

Comment: asharah & akevin9099

Comment: but expected: `had a great time with <a href="http://example.com/sarah333">@sarah333</a> and <a href="http://example.com/kevin9099">@kevin9099</a>  at beach.`

Comment: seems like you copy solution from Vegeta answer

Comment: Oh so now you are copying someone's code and decorating with HTML??